# How to increase Redmine custom field name text size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

I'm using Redmine 2.2.0. For my project requirement I to need create a custom field with more than 30 chars. I have tried modifying custom_fields table name column def from `varchar(30`) to `varchar(60)` but it didn't work. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Change redmine[root]\app\models\custom_field.rb

`validates_length_of :name, :maximum => 30` 
 to 
`validates_length_of :name, :maximum => 60`

and modify the custom_field table "name" column to varchar(60)

if this helped please make it as a answer.

happy redmine time :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to edit the custom field in the Administration panel and modify the settings?
In this page, you should be able to edit min and max length.

Comment: Yes.But not working.Anything needs to do in the backend?